# Python bytearray inside string problems

Tags: python, arrays, string, type-conversion, byte

I have a function to convert bytearrays into bytes:

```
def dehex(d):
        return bytes(bytearray(d))

test = dehex([0xe7,0xcd,0xb0,0xa2])
```

this works perfectly fine

**However**

I have a few saved bytearrays like the one above inside a txt file using pickle, that looks like this:

```
0xe7,0xcd,0xb0,0xa2
```

and i want to be able to load them from the txt file, the problem arises  if i read the file it returns a string which doesn't work with my dehex function.
it is like it gets interpreted as such:

`dehex(["0xe7,0xcd,0xb0,0xa2"])`

how would i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
my_str = "0xe7,0xcd,0xb0,0xa2" # String read from file.

my_bytes_list = [bytes.fromhex(c[2:]) for c in my_str.split(",")]

result = [dehex(bytes.fromhex(c[2:])) for c in my_str.split(",")]

print (result)
```

**Output:**

```
[b'\xe7', b'\xcd', b'\xb0', b'\xa2']
```

Comment: @EmilB Your function is called in the third line

Comment: this doesnt work, maybe i if i could turn it into a string somehow

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What needs to be turned into string? Also, could you please mention some exact expected output along with the corresponding input, passed to the function. Right now, in my answer, the string `'e7'` is being passed to `dehex` to get the `bytes` value `b'\xe'`, `'cd'` is passed to get `b'\xcd'`, `'b0'` is passed to get `b'\xb0'`, and finally, the string `'az'` is passed to get the `bytes` value `b'\xaz'`. If this is not what is expected, please specify the exact output expected.

Comment: Nevermind i got it working, thank you for your advice